# How to display a profile form using profile2 module

Tags: 7, users

Profile2 is a module that uses entities to create profiles that are separate from the user account.

From within my module, I want to be able to display a form to edit the profile entities. Possibly using drupal_get_form or maybe Profile2's API or any other method.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I did something like this recently. Since profile uses fields, this make things pretty simple. For the form you could do something like this:

```
function my_profile_form($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if (!isset($form_state['profiles'])) {
    $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user, 'profile_machine_name');
    if (!$profile) {
      $profile = profile_create(array(
        'type' => 'profile_machine_name',
        'uid' => $user->uid
      ));
    }
    $form_state['profiles'][$profile->type] = $profile;
  }

  // Use field attach form and handle the fields yourself:
  field_attach_form('profile2', $profile, $form, $form_state);
  // Or use profile2 API which is simpler
  profile2_attach_form($form, $form_state);

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Since all the profile form only is the fields that are attached to the profile, you can simply attach the fields yourself to the form, using Drupal core APIs:

- `field_attach_form` adds the fields to the form.
- `field_attach_validate` handles validation.
- `field_attach_submit` to handles adding the values to the entity (profile).
- Lastly you would need to save the profile entity using `profile2_save`.

After browsing the profile2 module code, I found that it provides a wrapper function to attach the fields to the form and save the form. This is simpler, but in doing so, you loose a little control. To use this you need to use the `profile2_attach_form`. Doing this will also handle the validation and saving of data.

To use the above code you should be able to c/p it, rename the form and replace `profile_machine_name` with the actual machine name of the profile you want to display the form for.

Comment: I don't understand what's happening here. I just need to display the Profile2 form. Is this possible?

Comment: when I use your code in my module it gives me this error: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\working\modules\field\field.attach.inc on line 550

Comment: @Charlie I've update my answer with more details and provided an alternative and simpler solution using profile2 API.

Comment: this is it googletorp!!! your answer worked with a minor edit: at the end of the function I added: return $form  that was the only way I could get it to display by calling it with drupal_get_form(). If there was an alternative way to display it without the return $form then please explain, otherwise thank you very much!

Comment: I have to wait 12 hours to award the bounty :)

Comment: Just did the exact same thing (using profile2_attach_form()) on one of my sites. Could you imagine profile2 in core? That would rock! (Hopefully it happens in D8).

Comment: This works until one of the profile fields gets erased. After that you can no longer edit it.