# How to add Profile2 form to ctools multistep wizard

Tags: users, chaos-tool-suite

I've been basing this off of Grashmash's article over [building a multistep registration with Ctools](http://www.grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7-using-ctools), and I can't seem to get the Profile2 form in. I don't want to use the Field Group multistep option as I need to add additional forms to the wizard, but I'd like to get past this first.

I can successfully get past the initial account creation, but then the profile doesn't show up. Any ideas?

```
    $form_info = array(
    // Specify unique form id for this form.
    'id' => 'multistep_registration',
    //Specify the path for this form. It is important to include space for the $step argument to be passed.
    'path' => "user/register/%step",
    // Show breadcrumb trail.
    'show trail' => TRUE,
    'show back' => FALSE,
    'show return' => FALSE,
    // Callback to use when the 'next' button is clicked.
    'next callback' => 'kidb_register_subtask_next',
    // Callback to use when entire form is completed.
    'finish callback' => 'kidb_register_subtask_finish',
    // Callback to use when user clicks final submit button.
    'return callback' => 'kidb_register_subtask_finish',
    // Callback to use when user cancels wizard.
    'cancel callback' => 'kidb_register_subtask_cancel',
    // Specify the order that the child forms will appear in, as well as their page titles.
    'order' => array(
        'register' => t('Register'),
        'profile' => t('Complete Profile'),
        ),
    // Define the child forms. Be sure to use the same keys here that were user in the 'order' section of this array.
    'forms' => array(
        'register' => array(
            'form id' => 'user_register_form'
            ),
        'profile' => array(
            'form id' => 'profile2_edit_main_profile_form',
            // Be sure to load the required include file if the form callback is not defined in the .module file.
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a similar thread, works perfectly with ctools.

[How to display a profile form using profile2 module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/how-to-display-a-profile-form-using-profile2-module)